# PycURL installation on Python 3.7.0 (Windows 10)

Tags: python, python-3.x, winforms, pycurl

I'm having a problem to install PycURL on the following environment

**Environment**

```
Python 3.7.0
Windows 10
```

**Problem**

```
C:\>pip install pycurl
Collecting pycurl
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e8/e4/0dbb8735407189f00b33d84122b9be52c790c7c3b25286826f4e1bdb7bde/pycurl-7.43.0.2.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Please specify --curl-dir=/path/to/built/libcurl

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 10 in C:\Users\user01\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-xrandomx\pycurl\

C:\>
```

According to the official site ... http://pycurl.io/docs/latest/install.html#official-packages

> Currently official PycURL packages are built against the following
>   Python versions:
>
> ```
> 2.7.10
> 3.2.5
> 3.3.5
> 3.4.3
> 3.5.2
> 3.6.0
> ```

Does it mean I have to uninstall current Python 3.7.0 and install 3.6.0 to make it works?

Is there any alternative?

Comment: You probably may want to use also tag `python` not only `python-3.x` to achieve more views.

Answer (score 17):

You have two major options:

- compile pycurl for Python 3.7 manually (starting point to dig is [here](http://pycurl.io/docs/7.19.5.1/install.html#winbuild-py))
- use unofficial binary of pycurl

Latter is much easier.

Most famous site with unofficial binaries is [this one](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/). Download `whl` file of pycurl matching your python version and python architecture from [here](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pycurl). Install downloaded file with pip:

`pip install C:/path/to/downloaded/file/pycurl‑7.43.1‑cp37‑cp37m‑win_amd64.whl`

Answer (score 0):

You'd better remove or reorder the pycurl in the installing file. And please don't install from the unofficial source. The above binary may have the highly unknown risk