# Cant install PyCurl

Tags: python, curl, installation, pip, pycurl

i tried to install py curl but i get this error...

```
pip install pycurl
Collecting pycurl
  Using cached pycurl-7.43.0.6.tar.gz (222 kB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 10:
     command: 'c:\users\lequi\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\lequi\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-vgtj42e_\\pycurl\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\lequi\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-vgtj42e_\\pycurl\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\lequi\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-y5vol4q7'
         cwd: C:\Users\lequi\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-vgtj42e_\pycurl\
    Complete output (1 lines):
    Please specify --curl-dir=/path/to/built/libcurl
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 10: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

Can someone Help?

Answer (score 0):

An answer was already given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53492993/pycurl-installation-on-python-3-7-0-windows-10). Try downloading and compiling pycurl manually